# About the difference between the enclitic "ne" and the non-enclitic "ne"

Tags: word-comparison, enclitic, interrogative

So, I know that -ne is an enclitic to express a yes/no question.

But, the "Ne", as a non-enclitic, as I understood it, could also be a word question.

In "Ne....annon" or "Ne....necne"

Meaning Is it.... or no? (French "Est-ce que" would express it better)

- Is it the same "ne" and when you use it in conjonction with "annon" and "necne" it becomes a separated (non-enclitic) word?
- From what: Could I use the enclitic "-ne" in conjonction with "annon" or "necne"?
- And could I use the interrogative non-enclitic "Ne..." alone?
- How "Ne..." is different from "-ne...."?

(All these questions can have the same answer).

Comment: Can you provide an actual, attested example of non-enclitic ne used as a question word in a direct question? It's true that *enclitic* -ne can be used with annon/necne in *indirect* questions to mean 'whether...or not,' but I've never seen the usage that you're describing. Still ne might be paired with quidem, and the whole sentence might just happen to be a direct question; but in that case, ne isn't an interrogative word.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with, they aren't actually the same "word", as they have a different vowel.  The *e* in *-ne* is short whilst the *e* in *ne* is long.  Also, the non-enclitic *ne* is not primarily an interrogative word at all but a subordinating conjunction that introduces negative clauses that would be introduced by *ut* if not negative (though the other way around with verbs of fear).  In many situations its best English translation is *lest*.